# Is std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN() cross platform safe?

Tags: c++, double, cross-platform, nan

In a c++ app I've created for an armhf board I get the gps longitude and latitude decimal values and store it to double variables. For the time being I initialize these variable to an invalid value (255).
However I came across that by using `std::numeric_limits` one can assign a double variable to `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()`.
Regarding the nan cross platform issues I read the quite useful link [Should I use floating point's NaN, or floating point + bool for a data set that contains invalid values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574192/should-i-use-floating-points-nan-or-floating-point-bool-for-a-data-set-that)
On the other hand `std::numeric_limits` is a pure c++11 standard but I was wondering if someone has experienced any problems when porting this kind of code in different platforms.
For example if I move my code from a hard to soft floating
or even an amd64 platform will the above initialization cause any problems that should be handled with OS preprocessor directives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [cppreference:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/has_quiet_NaN) "The value of std::numeric_limits::has_quiet_NaN is true for all types T capable of representing the special value "Quiet Not-A-Number". This constant is meaningful for all floating-point types and is guaranteed to be true if std::numeric_limits::is_iec559 == true."

You would need to check for the soft floating point library or FPU to be IEEE 754 (IEC 559) compliant, and also that you use the correct compiler flags to enable their use see: [gcc-flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath) for floating point.

Answer (score 0):

BTW: I wrote the accepted answer for the question you refer to.

Myself, I am quite a fan of NaNs, and would be willing to do what you asked for.

@AdvSphere correctly points out that this is a language standard statement, so it should be portable within the restrictions that your system be IEEE-754 / IEC-759 compliant.

RECOMMENDATION: do not #ifdef your code so that it runs on systems that do not support quietNaNs properly.  But I recommend #ifdeffing your code to detect such systems (where possible) and refused to compile. BONUS POINTS if you provide or point to sn FP validation suite that detects such systems that do not provide full quiet NaN support, even if it looks like they do from the point of view of compiled code.

---+ binary FP data in files

However, you may not be able to exchange binary data in Files this is a language statement. The representation of QNaNs can differ between systems, particularly for early IEEE-754. (Anecdote: I had a friend who wrote a very efficient physics code, and submitted it to a contest for a public standard. I think in part he hoped that this would be a career kudo for him, helping him get jobs in the sort of physics programming he . It was rejected because it stored raw binary IEEE FP data in files. But that was long ago, and might not be a problem nowadays.)

---+ how much much IEEE FP support is there really in your target system?

Note that many systems support IEEE-754 *formats* including QNaNs, but do not necessarily support completely standard QNaN behavior. So do not rely on marketing statements like "our hardware supports IEEE floating point".  Do not simply look the data yourself in a debugger and say "that looks like IEEE FP".

What about if they have std::numeric_limits::has_quiet_NaN?

A: make sure they also have is_iec559 == true.

Q1: is an implementation allowed to set has_quiet_NaN is is_iec559 is false?

A: I may be wrong, but I think they are allowed to do so. Certainly the standard language quoted by the previous answer would allow this. Although there might be other language that prevents it, and I assume that I will be corrected if that is the case.

E.g. There are compiler switches for optimizations that assume that they will encounter no NaNs, quiet or otherwise.  do those compiler switches change the value of is_iec559?

There are also optimizers that are outside the C/C++ language tool chain. E.g. Optimizers that act on binaries. Dynamic on the fly JIT optimizers that act on binaries. That may or may not enforce C++ standard rules. Also, some code baby generated by tools before or C++, and make similar assumptions. Digital libraries.  If you are reasonably certain that your code will not be used in such an environment, you should be safe.  Such outside the compiler optimization tools are much more common in super computer/HPC environments than they Are in mass market PCs. Unfortunately, engineering and scientific workstations may be on the borderline.

Q: can you trust is_iec559?

A: of course you can! It's the language standard! Nobody would ever set it incorrectly by accident or a bug. No marketing department might ever ask for a simple "lie" in order to win a big sale.   (Sorry, but I have worked in companies where exactly this sort of deception was suggested.)

Anyway: barring fraud or bugs, I would trust is_iec559.  But I would feel happier if I could run some IEEE FP test suite myself, in addition. Run it myself, not just rely on the vendor having done so. Although I might only be paranoid enough to do this in a safety critical app like code for a nuclear power plant. Not your problem AFAICT.

---+ performance

The performance caveats for NaNs still apply. Q: is it acceptable if your apps performance is 1000x slower for some inputs? Two or 4X slower? Or will your users think that it has hung, and sending expensive tech-support calls.

---+ Detection latency

Quiet NaNs are quiet.

I.e. if you are using them for uninitialized data, you won't see a signal or exception at the first use of such uninitialized data. It might propagate all the way to the end. Slowing down your program significantly. Possibly being almost impossible to trace.

Signaling NaNs or what you really need to detect use of uninitialized data bugs. But IIRC standard support for signaling NaNs is much weaker, because hardware support for signaling NaNs is much less common. Eg the GPU that provide quiet NaN support often can't do at all, at least not precisely.

---+ semantics

Just like compilers may do optimizations that may or may not propagate QNaNs correctly, humans also ha r such coding issues. And it's not just optimizations.

E.g. There are versions of MAX and MIN that propagate or signal NaNs, and there are versions that do not.  e.g. think about missing data: sometimes you want to compute the average anyway and put a footnote on it, sometimes you want to throw away the operation.

Is the human programmer calling the correct version of max and count?

E.g. if you are calling the version of MAX that ignores NaNd if there are any valid values, but if you just divide the length of the vector, and not by the number of non-NaN values in the input vector, your averages will be incorrect.  Hopefully standard routines will do this properly.  Q: will you be doing this properly? Q: if you are using any nonstandard libraries written by somebody else, do you know that they are doing it properly?  This is something that the compiler cannot tell for you: as far as it knows  the code may be explicitly telling it to ignore NaNs, but the programmer didn't realize it was an issue.

---+ Valid

BTW although in the answer to the earlier question you refer to, I advocated Valid templates, that only really "solves" the problem if you can compile all of your code. You are unlikely to be able to pass a template through to library code that you have not written.

However, sometimes I wear the hat of trying to influence language standards: I would really like language standards to provide a std::Valid template type for all data types. Integer as well as floating point.  Using an extra bit if necessary, but defined so that if NaNs our properly supported they can be used instead of the extra bit.

However, you can see that I have not been very successful on that particular bit of evangelism.  Uninitialized date bugs are still all over the place, and still rank fairly high on CVE list of security bugs. IMHO such security bugs will persist until hardware support with at least 1 tag bit per 32 bits of data (preferably per byte) is provided.  We always say that software can solve problems that hardware should not, but the resistance of the software community to solving these problems is historically overwhelming. Hardware tag memory is coming back, looks like it will be common in some systems within five years, but I predict it will take at least a decade more before software standards rely on it.  Although perhaps if hardware tag support is present in some but not all systems, language standards will finally provide things like Valid so that portable code can run safely on systems both with and without hardware tagged memory for uninitialized data.

(Sorry about the rant. No, I don't apologize for the rant. As you can see I have worked on code optimization and security. They are not all unrelated. Although most of my career I have spent on the hardware side, I'm still software guy at hard, and it just pisses me off that the inertia of software standards gets so much in the way of appropriate hardware/software trade-offs.)

---+ CONCLUSION

Even with all these caveats, I remain a fan of using NaNs.

They are the right thing to do if ubiquitously supported.

I'm just mentioning issues to be sensitive about. Heck, in someways I am just mentioning the things that opponents of hardware support for NaNs have thrown in my face.  Some of which I've actually encountered myself.  Most of which have been encountered by some niche customer somewhere.  But you don't have to worry about niche customers, you only have to worry about your old code running on your target systems.

I want people to use NaNs successfully. I want no unpleasant surprises.  Unfortunately, after the first IEEE FP standard, people started using NaNs and had so many unpleasant surprises that coding standards started recommending "never use NaNs".  We are mostly past that, but there are still places where you can trip up. I don't mind if you trip, as long as you expect that's such problems can occur, and ready to handle them, or even better ca say "I can't guarantee this on the system because it may not support Nan's properly"

RECOMMENDATION: don't #ifdef your code so that it runs on systems that don't properly support QNaNs.

But I recommend #ifdef'ing your code to detect such systems, so that you can refuse to compile.